# remove last N lines from file bash

Tags: bash, sed

i am trying to remove some text from a file, i need to find the line number using a string and then remove from that line to the end of the file.

i tried using sed and outputting to a new file using a string as a search term but it does not keep the lines, it just prints the whole file on one line, which isnt helpful as the rest of the script relies on line numbers.
my code so far is:

```
file=$(sed -ie '/<div class="col-wrapper">/,$d' < file1.txt)  
echo $file > file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use inline editing in `sed`:

```
sed -i '/<div class="col-wrapper">/,$d' file1.txt
```

to save changes to `file1.txt`

Comment: Damn, I thought I tried that! Now I feel totally stupid! Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/<div class="col-wrapper">/Q' file1.txt
```

Comment: Anubahava's answer worked great already, could you explain the difference between GNU sed and normal sed?

Comment: @JONAS402 GNU sed has addional commands see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands). In  this case `Q` quits the processing of the file without printing the address it matches. Perhaps a more efficient solution if the file is long and the match near the front of the file.